# How to crop corners of a 1000x1000 picture

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to crop a picture to 1000 by 1000 pixels. It works to crop the far left of the picture.

```
img = Image.open('image.jpg')
(width, height) = img.size
if width >= height:
    multiplier = 1000 / height
    height = int(height * multiplier + 1)
    width = int(width * multiplier + 1)
    img = img.resize((width, height))
    cropped_img = img.crop((0,0, 1000,1000))
    cropped_img.save("background_image.png")
if height >= width:
    multiplier = 1000 / width
    width = int(width * multiplier + 1)
    height = int(height * multiplier + 1)
    img = img.resize((height, width))
    cropped_img = img.crop((0,0, 1000,1000))
    cropped_img.save("background_image.png")
```

However, if I attempt to change the crop to the far right it returns an error:

SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image

```
img = Image.open('image.jpg')
(width, height) = img.size
if width >= height:
    multiplier = 1000 / height
    height = int(height * multiplier + 1)
    width = int(width * multiplier + 1)
    img = img.resize((width, height))
    cropped_img = img.crop((1000,1000, 0, 0))
    cropped_img.save("background_image.png")
if height >= width:
    multiplier = 1000 / width
    width = int(width * multiplier + 1)
    height = int(height * multiplier + 1)
    img = img.resize((height, width))
    cropped_img = img.crop((1000,1000, 0, 0))
    cropped_img.save("background_image.png")
```

Comment: I believe this error message is saying that the third coordinate must be larger than the first coordinate, and the fourth coordinate must be larger than the second coordinate. So to crop on the right side, you need to set the left coordinate to the width minus 1000. See docs: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=crop#PIL.Image.Image.crop

Comment: Right.  The parameters are left, top, right, bottom.  You probably want `(width-1000, height-1000, width, height)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments and the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=crop#PIL.Image.Image.crop) pointed out, parameters should be supplied in the form of `(left, upper, right, lower)`.

In your case, this translates to `(width - 1000, height - 1000, width, height)`